# nvd3 discrete bar chart doesnot take entire svg area

Tags: css, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I am having this problem with Vertical bar chart using nvd3 where the chart which I add to the svg is not taking the entire area of svg, hence not a aligning properly. 
the picture below you can see that in the box 5 the chart is taking only the right most area and not taking up the entire box.

Can someone help on how i can fix this? I have been on this for hours and have not found anything useful online.

TIA

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying a lot of hacks, I figured out the reason the chart was not aligning in svg properly was because of hard coded values for margin of the chart in the nv.d3.js library itself.

[image]

Changing the margin values in line 3208 helped me fit the chart properly.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably too late to help you with this issue, but I'll take a crack at it for the next person who comes along. I haven't tested this for the discrete bar chart, but I know that it works for the pie chart.

Set the chart's margin to a negative value - `.margin({top: -20, right: -20, bottom: -20, left: -20})`

My results:

**Before**

[image: Before]

**After**

[image: After]

Slightly off center... but you get the gist of it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped to find out the actual solution

Answer (score 1):

Taking in to account you haven't specified any code I'm going to take a guess how to fix your problem....

If your calling your chart like this in html

```
     <div id="chart1">
            <svg></svg>
     </div>
```

Make sure you have CSS like this -

```
#chart1 {
height: 600px;
width: 600px;
float: left;
margin-top: 60px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Or if you want to set the width and height in the javascript, edit your code to look like like this  -

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.discreteBarChart()
    .x(function(d) { return d.label })
    .y(function(d) { return d.value })
    .staggerLabels(true)
    .tooltips(false)
    .showValues(true)
    .options({ height: 600,
     width: 600,
     });
```

Hope this helps

Comment: it helps in spacing but the left side gap is still there. It is still not able to take the entire svg.